# Django: pass information between apps

Tags: python, django

I've two models in two different apps, In the firs one I'm asking my user biography information in the second one they have question to answer. I'd like to save in my database not only the answers but also the id code created in the account models file and use the userinformation answer to create the string name to use in the database but it gives me error  `"'ImportError: cannot import name 'name' from 'accounts.models' "`  even if I've imported the modules- This is my code:

```
**accounts.models** 
class UserInformation(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    birthday = models.DateField()
    age = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    id = models.CharField(max_length=250)   
 
    def __str__(self):
    self.name + '_' + self.lastname + '_' + str(self.birthday.year)

        if self.id_code =="":
            self.id_code = self.name + '_' + self.lastname + '_' + str(self.birthday.year)
            self.save()
            super(UserInformation, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

```
**accounts.forms.py**
class UserInformationForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = UserInformation
       fields = ('name', 'lastname', 'birthday', 'phone')
```

```
**accounts.views.py**
def add_information(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
      form = UserInformationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
      if form.is_valid():
          form.instance.user = request.user
          form.save()           
          return redirect('home')      
  else:
      form = UserInformationForm()
  return render(request, 'add_information.html', {'form': form})
```

```
**question.models.py**
from accounts.models import name

class QuestionOne(models.Model):
   question_1a = models.CharField(max_length=250, choices=point)
   question_2a = models.CharField(max_length=250, choices=point)
   question_3a = models.CharField(max_length=250, choices=point)
   id_code = models.CharField(max_length=250) 

   def __str__(self):
       return self.name + '_question_1'

class QuestionTwo(models.Model):
   question_1b = models.CharField(max_length=250, choices=point)
   question_2b = models.CharField(max_length=250, choices=point)
   question_3b = models.CharField(max_length=250, choices=point)
   id_code = models.CharField(max_length=250) 

   def __str__(self):
       return self.name + '_question_2'
```

```
**question.forms.py**
class QuestionOneForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = QuestionOne
       fields = ('question_1a', 'question_2a', 'question_3a')

class QuestionTwoForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = QuestionOne
       fields = ('question_1b', 'question_2b', 'question_3b')
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Apparently `name` is not a model or a function defined in `account.models`. You cannot import an attribute from a model. Also, its not clear how you want to use it. You may need to instantiate the model that has the attribute you need in order to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You must use a Foreign key and remove illegal import:

```py
class QuestionOne(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey("accounts.userinformation", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   question_1a = models.CharField(max_length=250, choices=point)
   question_2a = models.CharField(max_length=250, choices=point)
   question_3a = models.CharField(max_length=250, choices=point)
   id_code = models.CharField(max_length=250) 

   def __str__(self):
       return self.user.name + '_question_1'
```

Comment: Thanks! I've added `user = models.OneToOneField(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` this to my code, but it still not working. Should I use ForeignKeyField? Because I'd ike my user to be able to submit the form only once

Comment: You can use `models.ForeignKey("accounts.userinformation", on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=True)`. But OneToOne field should work, what is your error?

Comment: This is the error: ` Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <User: admin>>": "QuestionOne.user" must be a "UserInformation" instance.`

Comment: In your code you use `form.instance.user = request.user` but you should use an instance of `UserInformation` in your model. Or use `OneToOneField` in `UserInformation` model to `auth.User` and use: `form.instance.user = request.user.userinformation` in your view.

Comment: Another solution is `models.ForeignKey("auth.user", on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=True)`

Comment: I corrected the code and tried this  
 ` def __str__(self):
        return userinformation.first_name` and it gives me back this error 'name 'userinformation' is not defined' aso before I was able to display in my html page the answers selected using '{{ user.questionone.question_1 }} and now it's not working anymore

Comment: use `self.user.first_name`